# Exception: Notice: Undefined variable: _ENV

Tags: magento2

When saving any configuration in the admin I get this;

```
> Exception: Notice: Undefined variable: _ENV in
> /home/selectli/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Processor/EnvironmentPlaceholder.php
> on line 57 in
> /home/selectli/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/selectli/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Processor/EnvironmentPlaceholder.php(57):
> Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined varia...',
> '/home/selectli/...', 57, Array) #1
> /home/selectli/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/PreProcessorComposite.php(35):
> Magento\Config\Model\Config\Processor\EnvironmentPlaceholder->process(Array)
> #2 /home/selectli/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader.php(60):
> Magento\Framework\App\Config\PreProcessorComposite->process(Array) #3
> /home/selectli/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader/Proxy.php(95):
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader->read() #4
> /home/selectli/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(292):
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader\Proxy->read() #5
> /home/selectli/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(191):
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->readData() #6
> /home/selectli/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(152):
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->loadDefaultScopeData('default')
> #7 /home/selectli/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(131):
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/newreli...') #8
> /home/selectli/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(80):
> Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/newreli...') #9
> /home/selectli/public_html/vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting/Model/Config.php(91):
> Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('newrelicreporti...') #10
> /home/selectli/public_html/vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting/Plugin/HttpPlugin.php(49):
> Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\Config->isNewRelicEnabled() #11
> /home/selectli/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121):
> Magento\NewRelicReporting\Plugin\HttpPlugin->beforeCatchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception)) #12
> /home/selectli/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
> Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap),
> Object(Exception)) #13
> /home/selectli/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(39):
> Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('catchException',
> Array, Array) #14
> /home/selectli/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261):
> Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap),
> Object(Exception)) #15 /home/selectli/public_html/index.php(39):
> Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
> #16 {main}
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: I am getting the same error. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is due to something is missing in system.xml in third party module or custom module. In my case mageplaza smtp module missing tag in system.xml 
after put this in system.xml everything is working :)